# San Francisco to Sedona, Grand Canyon, Antelope(and Horseshoe bend)

Tags: routes

What would be a good route to cover Sedona, Grand Canyon and Antelope Canyon from San Francisco?

I do not wish to drive to Sedona from SFO, instead take a flight to nearest of above places and then go around these places.

I am new completely so not sure everything can be covered this way or I am being too greedy here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[Flagstaff Pulliam Airport](https://www.flagstaff.az.gov/1541/Flagstaff-Airport) (FLG) is the nearest airport to all three of these destinations with commercial flights. I was able to find round trip flights from SFO for under $200 on AA.

From the airport, there is little difference in driving distance if you rearrange the destinations, as long as Sedona is either first or last, but going in the order you listed, Sedona, Grand Canyon and Antelope Canyon is perfectly reasonable and will give you a lot of scenic driving between the points.

You can put multiple destinations into Google Maps and play around with rearranging them, if you wish, but you'll not likely come up with anything shorter.

Of course, while you can drive between all these points in a single day, you probably will want to spend more than a few minutes at each one! Keep this in mind when you are planning your drive.

[image: Google Maps driving directions screenshot]